# App crashes and gives NullPointerException error when trying to set up Gmail API for Android

Tags: java, android, gmail-api

I've been trying to set up gmail api for an android app but it has been unsuccessful. I'm running this quickstart code on the official doc
[Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java)

Following the three steps on the page, the Gmail api has been enabled in console, credentials.json file has also been downloaded and added to assets folder in android studio

When I run the quickstart code which is suppose to display the labels in my email, the app crashes and i get this error

```
Process: com.example.receiveemail, PID: 20339
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.receiveemail/com.example.receiveemail.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:770)
    at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:127)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeFlow$Builder.setTransport(AuthorizationCodeFlow.java:545)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow$Builder.setTransport(GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.java:254)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow$Builder.setTransport(GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.java:152)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeFlow$Builder.<init>(AuthorizationCodeFlow.java:494)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow$Builder.<init>(GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.java:195)
    at com.example.receiveemail.MainActivity.getCredentials(MainActivity.java:111)
    at com.example.receiveemail.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:69)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6666)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2677)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

MainActivity

```
package com.example.receiveemail;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.GmailScopes;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Label;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.ListLabelsResponse;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";


private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Gmail API Java Quickstart";
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

/**
 * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
 * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
 */
private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS);
private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/assets/credentials.json";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = null;

    try {
        HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Gmail service = null;

    try {
        service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    // Print the labels in the user's account.
    String user = "me";
    ListLabelsResponse listResponse = null;

    try {
        listResponse = service.users().labels().list(user).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    List<Label> labels = listResponse.getLabels();
    if (labels.isEmpty()) {
        Log.v(TAG, "No labels found.");

    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "Labels:");
        for (Label label : labels) {
            Log.v(TAG, label.getName());
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Creates an authorized Credential object.
 * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
 * @return An authorized Credential object.
 * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
 */
private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in = MainActivity.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();
    LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
}
}
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.receiveemail"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}

dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
  implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0'
  implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
  }
  implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev98-1.25.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
  }
  implementation 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'

  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

 android {
   packagingOptions {
     exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
  }
}
```

Here is the API page for Android [G Suite APIs for Android](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/guides/android)
 but it doesn't provide any instruction on how to set up the api, only the dependencies to include

Comment: What is line 111 in MainActivity? Something there is null that shouldn't be

Comment: GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

Comment: i'm thinking maybe the credential.json file is not properly linked. Can you help me check if the file path is correct. I mean the `private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH`

Comment: where have you placed the credentials file?

Comment: in assets folder

Comment: "Copy the credentials.json file you downloaded in Step 1 into the src/main/resources/ directory you just created." The tutorial says to place it here.

Comment: ok,what should be the value of the CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH field?  should i change to `/resources/credentials.json`

Comment: in the tutorial it is simply `"/credentials.json";`

Comment: still the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation provided for Java doesn't seem to work well for Android. I faced the same issues while working on G-Mail API. Use this piece of code to get credential and service:

```
mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES)).setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
mService = new com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail.Builder(
        transport, jsonFactory, credential)
        .setApplicationName(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
        .build();
```

Further, you can't run this code on the main thread since it involves network operations. Use AsyncTask to execute this code. I used this [github project](https://github.com/androidmads/JavaMailwithGmailApi) as a guide to integrate Gmail API into my Android app.

Comment: did you try to generate the OAuth key as specified in the tutorial? What i've generated is the OAuth 2.0 client ID, is it the same?

Comment: The API console procedure is same

Comment: Hi Charan, the api is working fine now but there's an issue. When i change email account from the button to another email address different from the one i used to generate the credentials, then it stops working. 
If I try to generate the credential from this email address, i get an error that the SHA1 fingerprint key is already being used
How can i make it possible that when a user chooses a different email account from the button, it still works correctly?
Any help here? thanks

Comment: You mean after selecting the email id from the list of mails right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean

Comment: Hey Charan, forgot to request for authorization from the other email id, working perfectly now. Thanks

Comment: No problem. Happy coding :)