# How to replace AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp class?

Tags: java, android, google-sheets-api

I am trying to run sample code from [Google Quickstart for Java](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/java) on an Android emulator, but the code falls on this line

```
return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receier).authorize("user");
```

It turned out that Android does not support `AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp` class, so you need to manually catch the URL address for authorization, open it in the browser and then put the result in the `Credential` object. I am familiar with Java superficially, so I don't really know how I can implement that.

Can you please tell how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

From this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54309890/app-crashes-and-gives-nullpointerexception-error-when-trying-to-set-up-gmail-api), Charan M uses this piece of code to get credential and service:

```
mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES)).setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
mService = new com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail.Builder(
        transport, jsonFactory, credential)
        .setApplicationName(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
        .build();
```

Do note that you can't run this code on the main thread since it involves network operations. They also provided a [github project](https://github.com/androidmads/JavaMailwithGmailApi) as a guide in integrating, in their case, Gmail API into their Android project.

Comment: Why I can't get account name then I already have mCredential?
I mean, that


    GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES)).setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
    Log.v("states", credential.getSelectedAccountName());


will give me a error. Am I do smth wrong?